# Making the query for more efficient

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

What I want is the Participants (people, with role as participant) of one event, combined with people of the same companies as that of participants, but whose role is manager.

A Person's role is stores in person_role_membership, but a person's company is stored in People. I have crafted the following query, which I think does the job pretty well. Please ignore the extra joins and information. I am fetching all the participants, then UNION-ing with all the managers, for which I am once again fetching all the participants. Now the trouble is this whole query, for a small subset is taking 9 seconds. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
select distinct * 
from 
(
SELECT 
 p.id as p_id, p.first_name as p_first_name, p.last_name as p_last_name,p_r.name as p_role, 
 p.job_title as p_job_title, 
 p_d.email as p_email, p_d.phone_1 as p_phone, p_d.phone_ext_1 as p_ext,
 c.name as p_company, p_c.name as p_parent_company

 FROM person_role_memberships as prm

 left join people as p on prm.person_id = p.id and prm.person_role_id between 32 and 35
 left join person_roles as p_r on p_r.id = prm.person_role_id
 left join person_details as p_d on p.id = p_d.person_id and p_d.type = 'BusinessDetail'
 left join companies as c on c.id = p.company_id
 left join companies as p_c on p_c.id = p.parent_company_id

 where 
 p.id is not null 

) as parts
union (

select p.id, p.first_name,p.last_name,prm.person_role_id, p.job_title,  'cp email', 'phone','ext',c.name, d.name

from people as p -- All those people

left join person_role_memberships as prm on prm.person_id = p.id -- whose roles are like this
left join companies as c on p.company_id = c.id
left join companies as d on c.parent_id = d.id
-- and whose companies are like those people whose roles are like this

where company_id = any
(
select company_id from people as p
left join person_role_memberships as prm on prm.person_id = p.id
where prm.person_role_id between 32 and 35-- and other conditions;
)

and (person_role_id = 14 or person_role_id = 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the 'any' part of your query is slowing things down. By the looks of it I think you don't even need it because you could filter on person_role_memberships directly:

```
select p.id, p.first_name,p.last_name,prm.person_role_id, p.job_title,  'cp email', 'phone','ext',c.name, d.name

from people as p -- All those people
    left join person_role_memberships as prm on prm.person_id = p.id -- whose roles are like this
    left join companies as c on p.company_id = c.id
    left join companies as d on c.parent_id = d.id

-- and whose companies are like those people whose roles are like this
where prm.person_role_id between 32 and 35 -- and other conditions;
    and (person_role_id = 14 or person_role_id = 15))
```

The 'any'-statement is causing the database to look through the entire PEOPLE table for every record.